# Pairwise Mahalanobis distance in R

Tags: r, distance, classification

I'm trying to calculate a Mahalanobis-type pairwise distance matrix in R. I have 33 individuals, each with 10 variables. The idea is to get a distance matrix D, where

$$D_{i,j}=(\mathbf{X}_i-\mathbf{X}_j)W^{-1}(\mathbf{X}_i-\mathbf{X}_j)^T$$

However I haven't been able build proper code for it.

Comment: Type `?mahalanobis` in `R` and look the documentation.

Comment: @MYaseen208: Wrong. Look below.

Comment: See also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65705/pairwise-mahalanobis-distance

Comment: The problem with the `mahalanobis` function in `R` as recommended by @MYaseen208 is that this calculates maha distance between a single point and a set of points, not pairwise distance between every pair of points in a set of points. See the post recommended by @rpierce for more discussion.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608280/mahalanobis-distance-with-multiple-observations-per-group/29614330#29614330

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me in similar example where R is a dataframe of 54 individuals and 8 variables. Mahalanobis distance Ma between individuals X1 and X2 can be computed as ff:

```
# express difference (X1-X2) as atomic row vector
d <- as.matrix(X1-X2)[1,] 

# solve  (covariance matrix) %*% x = d for x
x <- solve(cov(R),d)

# Mahalanobis calculation forced in two steps
Ma <- sum(d*x)
```

Comment: what are X1 and X2?...can you make this self contained?

Comment: Didn't you miss the square root of Ma?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `gendistance` function in the [nbpMatching package](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/MatchedRandomization#Matched_Randomization_R_Package)

Here's a short example modified from the help page, with two variables instead of 10:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:33, val1=rnorm(33), val2=rnorm(33))
df.dist <- gendistance(df, idcol=1)
df.dist$dist
```

The distance matrix will have a 34th row/column-- this is for use in matching, and you can ignore it.

Comment: thanks for the extra info. From what i understand of the OP's description the answer should be a vector with 33*32/2 positive numbers in it... –

Answer (score 0):

There a very easy way to do it using R Package "biotools".
In this case you will get a Squared Distance Mahalanobis Matrix.

```
#Manly (2004, p.65-66)

x1 <- c(131.37, 132.37, 134.47, 135.50, 136.17)
x2 <- c(133.60, 132.70, 133.80, 132.30, 130.33)
x3 <- c(99.17, 99.07, 96.03, 94.53, 93.50)
x4 <- c(50.53, 50.23, 50.57, 51.97, 51.37)

#size (n x p) #Means 
x <- cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4) 

#size (p x p) #Variances and Covariances
Cov <- matrix(c(21.112,0.038,0.078,2.01, 0.038,23.486,5.2,2.844, 
            0.078,5.2,24.18,1.134, 2.01,2.844,1.134,10.154), 4, 4)

library(biotools)
Mahalanobis_Distance<-D2.dist(x, Cov)
print(Mahalanobis_Distance)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to do it:

```
library("MASS")
library("ICSNP")

x0<-mvrnorm(33,1:10,diag(c(seq(1,1/2,l=10)),10))
x1<-pair.diff(x0) #C-implementation.
dM<-mahalanobis(x1,colMeans(x1),var(x1))
```

Following  Roman Luštrik's suggestion, here are more details. 
The OP asked for pairwise Mahalanobis distance, which are multivariate U-statistics of distance. I have first seen them mentionned in Croux et al. 94 [(below equation 6.4)](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/205831/1/gs.pdf) but i'm sure others such as Oja have explored this concept.

Comment: It would be helpful if you expanded your answer with at least a short comment on your code. Why do you use it that way, why this approach is better compared to another approach...

Comment: It would be helpful if you expanded your comment with at least a short description of what that "another approach" could be.

Comment: I leave that at your discretion. My point was that it would help others (including me) if you gave your answer some more context.

Comment: Here is a question from [@user21060](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/21060/user21060) who cannot leave comment at the moment: Should `var(x1)` be `var(x0)` instead as the $\sigma$ should be the variance of the original data, and I also question whether the empirical mean should be used here?

Comment: thanks to user21060 for the questions. The answers are no and yes. both should be for x1. I'm correcting the oversight now.

Comment: I have posted some theory giving the rationale behind the following code at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65705/pairwise-mahalanobis-distance/66325#66325 fastPwMahal = function(x1,invCovMat) { SQRT = with(svd(invCovMat), u %*% diag(d^0.5) %*% t(v)) dist(x1 %*% SQRT) } At the link above I have also shown that the (currently top-voted) solution using the ICSNP package on this forum seems to be incorrect. I joined stack exchange to answer this question, but initially did not have enough reputation to do so. I'm hoping a mod can arrange for these threads to be merged.

Comment: Please don't read anything into an answer that gets only 1 upvote, especially in a thread that was migrated here.  Migrations tend to go unnoticed and therefore may remain unchecked for a long time.

Comment: @ahfoss: you are confusing Mahalanobis distance (result of the mahalanobis() function in R) with *pairwise* Mahalanobis distance. The OP asked for the latter while the rest of the answers decided to interpret this to mean the former. In any case, these are two different estimators (except when the underlying data is symmetric about its mean).